# localhost configuration in offline mode

Tags: apache, offline

I'm in a very stupid situation and if I didn't get to resolve it my project will be rejected.
I doing a project for a company that they have hard network security and I can't publish the project online or in a local server.
I'm using on my project PHP and MySQL using usbwebserver program "it's offline Apache server".
now the problem is:
my project should to be on a network as a folder example: \server1\project
and to open the project on my computer I have to access the path and run usbwebserver.exe , so it is open perfect for 1 user but if I try to access the same project in other computer when the first user using the program the Apache not running and I think because the port of apache already in use."maybe I'm wrong"

my question is if there any solution that when other users on the network click on usbwebserver.exe
the apache become running on it  .. because I have to use the same DB.

If there is other program that can solve my situation to everyone can work on same apache and same DB offline also I will appreciate!!

Comment: stackoverflow is a solution oriented forum. Personal context has nothing to do in your question. If you need an urgent answer, I think there are paid options to get an answer faster, using the bounty system.

Answer (score 0):

I thinking in this way if it possible:
Install Apache on your machine and call mysql from server folder that doesn't run Apache!!!
it is possible ? and if yes how can done it ?

Comment: WOW nobody have any answer ?